# Запуск dos-овской программы через сайт

Tags: dos, javascript, php

Я никогда не интересовался и поэтому не знаю, возможно ли запустить досовскую программу через сайт (конечно сам догадываюсь, что это невозможно)?

Comment: Можно, если сервер поддерживает работу dos программ

Comment: Вам нужен выделенный (или VDS/VPS) сервер с виндой на броту. Есть такой?

Comment: Ну, или dosbox на линуксовском сервере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если интересна сама возможность, то это возможно, требуются соответствующие права.
В php существует для этого ряд функций, например [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) или [shell_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)